# Algorithm: Solve crossword puzzle given a list of words

Tags: ruby, algorithm, recursion, multidimensional-array

I looked at previous questions of similar problems, but I have a specific question related to this algorithm. The problem statement (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/crossword-puzzle/problem) is as follows:

A 10x10 Crossword grid is provided to you, along with a set of words (or names of places) which need to be filled into the grid. 
The cells in the grid are initially, either + signs or - signs. 
Cells marked with a + have to be left as they are. Cells marked with a - need to be filled up with an appropriate character.

Sample input:

```
+-++++++++
+-++++++++
+-++++++++
+-----++++
+-+++-++++
+-+++-++++
+++++-++++
++------++
+++++-++++
+++++-++++
LONDON;DELHI;ICELAND;ANKARA
```

Corresponding output:

```
+L++++++++
+O++++++++
+N++++++++
+DELHI++++
+O+++C++++
+N+++E++++
+++++L++++
++ANKARA++
+++++N++++
+++++D++++
```

I made the mistake of writing out an algorithm without fully understanding the problem, where I just put the next available letter in an empty spot and solving the maze that way (here's my code):

```
 def populate_grid(maze, locations)
     maze.each_index do |row|
         maze[row].each_index do |col|
             if maze[row][col] == "-"
                 maze[row][col] = locations.first[0]
                 if locations.first.length == 1
                     locations.shift # remove this location altogether
                 else
                    locations[0] = locations[0][1...locations.first.length]
                 end
                 populate_grid(maze, locations)
             end
         end
     end
 end
```

Unfortunately, there isn't a provided solution for this problem, and I'd like to know how to build the consistent directionality per word (e.g only goes in horizontal/vertical direction). I thought about using a 3 parameter as a Boolean for whether the word is going up or down, but that didn't seem feasible to me.

Anyone have ideas for how to preserve directionality?

Comment: You could solve the problem using recursion. Place the 1st word at each feasible location. For each, place the second word at each feasible position. For each pairing of the first and second, place the third word at each feasible position. Your recursive method might be written `recurse(partially_filled_crossword, remaining_words)`, both arguments being arrays, returning an array representing a completed crossword (array), or `nil` if no valid completed crossword exists for that part of the search tree.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you need to treat with the lexicon as *word* units, and handle the grid (that's the cruciverbalist's term for your `maze`) with routines to insert an entire word as a unit.

You'll need to "parse" the grid to identify all available locations.
Write a function to `match` a word to an available location, or vice versa.  A location consists of a starting square (row, col), direction (boolean), and letter pattern (blanks, except where a crossing word is already filled in).  `match` will consider word length and any squares already filled in.

Now, you can iterate over placing each word in turn, or filling each grid location.  Call `match` until you find a place to fill in a word.  If you find none, the current grid fill does not lead to a solution; backtrack one word and try again.  When you find a spot, fill in the word (another function), update any crossing locations with the now-filled letter, and go to the next word or location in your iteration.

If you reach the end successfully, you have a completed puzzle.

Does that get you moving?

Comment: Code would make this a much more useful answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I feel that designing the data structures and providing working code would go well beyond SO's general purpose.  I agree with OP that the posted code is an invalid attack; a proper change is a large rewrite.

Comment: I'm not criticising you answer, just making the point that code would be more helpful to the OP and other readers. One often sees answers that may be regarded as going "well beyond SO's general purpose", but are appreciated nonetheless.

Comment: Could you expand a bit more on the match method?

Comment: @Sunny: at this point, you've parsed the grid to find all locations.  You have these stored conveniently, such as an array whose entries each contain a length and the current pattern of letters.  You now have to write a `match` method that will return all locations that match a given word: the same length, and no conflicting letters.